# How to apply a Twitter Bootstrap tooltip to text wrapped in a <span>?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, html

Apparently you can add a Twitter Bootstrap [tooltip](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips) to any element that has the `.tooltip` class, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a[rel='tooltip'], .tooltip").tooltip();
});
```

However, adding this class to a span tag does not seem to work. Example:

```
<p>1 + 1 = <span class="tooltip" title="Wooo!">2</span></p>
```

Only links seem to work with tooltips. Example:

```
<p>2 + 2 = <a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="Wooo!">4</a></p>
```

Here's a jsFiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/ZznzE/

So how can I display a tooltip for text wrapped in a span?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a `class="tooltip"`, but a `rel="tooltip"`

Like this:

```html
<p>1 + 1 = <span rel="tooltip" title="Tip 1">2</span></p>
```

I updated your fiddle and it works fine now: http://jsfiddle.net/Xz2e7/1/

I also added a `cursor: pointer` to the CSS on the span tag. For usability this is better, so people know where there is interaction on the page.

**Edit:**

The tooltip class is not meant for using like you want to use it. the tooltip class is taking care of the tooltip itself (making it invisible when not hovering for example).

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Xz2e7/3/

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo in my post. Please see revision.

Comment: I still don't see the problem? Have you checked the fiddle I linked? don't you want a tooltip showing on a span tag, or did I misunderstand?

Comment: I don't want the span tag to have a `rel` attribute, because it's not a valid attribute (it's only meant to be used for link tags). I want the span tag to use the `.tooltip` class, or some other valid approach.